# Bottom Navigation Android - How to set icon state checked programatically on every current Fragment position

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So for example I have 1 **Activity** with 2 Fragments named **Fragment A.1** and **Fragment A.2**

When the **Activity** is first launched, by default it will immediately display **Fragment A.1** and `BottomNavigation` sets the Icon **Fragment A.1** to be active. Likewise, if I click `BottomNavigation` **Fragment A.2**, `BottomNavigation` also sets the **Fragment A.2** Icon to be active.

But the problem is if my current position is in **Fragment A.2** and I press the back button to **Fragment A.1**, then the `BottomNavigation` icon remains active in **Fragment A.2** even though my current position is already in **Fragment A.1**.

How do I set a dynamic icon, where the activity follows wherever my position is?

**bottomnavigation.xml**

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_colors"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_text_colors"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_bottom" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    pos = 0;
                    Fragment fragment = new Home();

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_wallet:
                    fragment = new Wallet();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm able to do this behaviour:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
                    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
                    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

bottom_navigation_colors.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/dark_red" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Selected fragment shows icon and text with **RED** color else **black**

Comment: Thank you sir, but I already achieve this behavior look at my code `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_colors"`. The real problem is when I say "_But the problem is if my current position..._"